JOLT : check if JSON contains special char , seperate json
I would like to ckeck if a JSON value contains special characters (in this case a pipe):
[
  {
    "item_original_no": "item1",
    "attribute": "PACKAGING_MATERIAL_1",
    "value": "PET"
  },
  {
    "item_original_no": "item2",
    "attribute": "colour",
    "value": "red|white|blue"
  }
]

if this is the case I would like to seperate the values. They should appear in different objects like in this target JSON
[
  {
    "item_original_no": "item1",
    "attribute": "PACKAGING_MATERIAL_1",
    "value": "PET"
  },
  {
    "item_original_no": "item2",
    "attribute": "colour",
    "value": "red"
  },
  {
    "item_original_no": "item2",
    "attribute": "colour",
    "value": "white"
  },
  {
    "item_original_no": "item2",
    "attribute": "colour",
    "value": "blue"
  }
]

I really do not know, if this is feasable with JOLT.
Thanks in adavance for your help and hint.

I don't know about the methods other than Jolt but it has a function called split, implementing it along with some upcoming shift transformations will handle what you need in this case such as
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "=split('\\|',@(1,&))" //splits the string by pipe chars if there exists any of them 
                                        //should be escaped by double pipes as a special character
      }
    }
  },
  {//the previous split function produces an array, namely "value"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": {//loop under the "value" array
          "*": {
            "@2": "@3,item_original_no.&1.Others",
            "@2,&1[&]": "@3,item_original_no.&1.&2"//partition by item_original_no along with indexes of the "value" array
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Others": {
            "*": "&3_&2.&",
            "value": { "": "" } //removes original "value" 
          },
          "*": "&2_&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1 is :


As always => A very good solution. I would have never thought of that. Thank you so much!!!

Sure thing, enjoy your study @KatjaBürger
